# Data from WebForm not being entered into Database (MySQL) PHP

Tags: php, mysql, database, web

I have built a website have built a registration form. I have managed to get a connection with no errors, however the data isn't being entered from the form into the database. The code I have for the PHP is below...

```
$dbhost="refereelink.mysql";
$dbuser="        ";
$dbpass="        ";
$dbname="refereelink_com";

$conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass)
or die (mysql_error());

mysql_select_db($dbname);


    if (isset($_POST['add'])){
        $firstname = $_POST['firstname'];
        $surname = $_POST['surname'];
        $dob = $_POST['dob'];
        $city = $_POST['city'];
        $r_country = $_POST['r_country'];
        $r_region = $_POST['r_region'];
        $r_level = $_POST['r_level'];
        $r_email = $_POST['r_email'];
        $r_contact_n = $_POST['r_contact_n'];
        $r_username = $_POST ['r_username'];
        $r_password =$_POST['r_password'];
        $membership_type =$_POST ['membership_type'];
        $insert=
            "INSERT INTO referees (firstname, surname, dob, city, r_country,  r_region, r_level, r_email, r_contact_n, r_username, r_password)
            VALUES    ('$firstname', '$surname', '$dob', '$city', '$r_county', '$r_region', '$r_level', '$r_email', '$r_contact_n', '$r_username', '$r_password')";
            mysql_query($insert) or die(mysql_error());
    }
```

Any help on this matter would be appreciated! I can't seem to work out what the issue is myself having checked it numerous times!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved the issue...

I had included an extra field in the php code that wasn't in the database... school boy error really! Should of picked it up...

Sjagr, reason for the host being as it is, is because its linked to the mysql from my domain host, so they set it to that and not local host unfortunately! It's a shame that my host doesn't allow access to local host with their service!

Answer (score 0):

```
$dbhost="refereelink.mysql";
```

What is that? Use `localhost` or the address of the MySQL server

You should also be wary of SQL injection and the fact that `mysql_*` is depreciated

Comment: Why is it almost always `localhost` ? Any architeture above a mom and pop shop is going to have the SQL server away from the web server.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy I don't think OP has gotten as far as a mom and pop shop, but duly noted and edited anyways